# CMake Tools just disappears prematurely when trying to use it in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

When opening Visual Studio Code with the CMake, CMake Tools, and C/C++ Extensions extensions installed, the options provided by CMake Tools initially appear, but disappear when clicked on. My finger isn't even released from my mouse before the options disappear. On top of this, the CMake Tools button which should be on the left-side pane of Visual Studio Code never appears.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83Vl_qnqpdc

This video above demonstrates this--before encountering this error, I followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAoTBg8MJJ4

Comment: There is, one for every .c file. I should mention that using the Command Pallette does not display any CMake commands, also

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] setup to reproduce the issue? Include what files are necessary and where to put them, and what versions of all your tools you have installed (VS Code, CMake, the CMake-tools VS Code extension). Do you get any related-looking messages in the output logs? (View > Output > CMake Language Server)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of the System version of VSCode (as opposed to the User version), the latest versions of the CMake extensions, and the raspberry pi pico sdk from https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk. CMake Tools has a custom environment variable of PICO_SDK_PATH set to C:\Pico\pico-sdk, an installation of the aforementioned pico-sdk repository. It also has a custom generator setting of "MinGW Makefiles" under "Cmake: Generator - The CMake Generator to use.", and under "Mingw search dirs - Directories where MinGW may be installed.", C:\Pico-Tools\MinGW is inputted.

Comment: I'm confident these are the correct paths, also @user

Comment: Give exact version numbers for posterity and clarity. And please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. Do you get any related-looking messages in the output logs? (View > Output > CMake Language Server) Show also relevant workspace settings.json file for a [mre]